# Is there a subjunctive tense in English?

Tags: tense, subjunctives

The following sentence come from The American Journal of the Medical Sciences by J.B. Lippincott:

> Unless **there be** some lesion of the stomach, there is no blood, either
>   microscopic or occult.

Is "there be" commonly used in English. It sounds like the subjunctive present tense, but I thought that there were no subjunctive tense in the English language? Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. There is no subjunctive tense, or mood. The subjunctive is a clause type. It is one of the three major constructions headed by a plain form verb, e.g. "It is vital that I be kept informed". Your example is an archaic use of the subjunctive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subjunctive mood exists in English. It is, as with most features of English grammar, formed with a combination of auxiliaries and much re-use of the few forms each verb takes. The simple present subjunctive uses the appropriate noun or pronoun and the bare infinitive - as you have with **there be** in your example.

Of course, present simple subjunctive used in *that* way isn't the popular any more. It's a little old-fashioned. We have other ways that are pretty popular.

> I recommend **that you not publish** that story.
>
> I insist **that you leave**.
>
> It is necessary **that you be** punished.

And then there's things that aren't simple present, of course.

> I wish **that I were** prettier
>
> I wouldn't do that, if **I were you**

Really, it feels like it would be pretty hard to do much without a subjunctive, but I don't doubt there are some languages that lack it utterly, somehow.